# Reportlab: Asian fonts with encryption enabled does not work

Tags: python, fonts, reportlab

I have been using Asian fonts (Chinese simplified/tradional, Japanese, and Korean) in my reportlab generated pdfs without issuse for a while now. However recently we have decided to enable the encryption options like this:

```
from reportlab.pdfbase import pdfmetrics
from reportlab.pdfbase.cidfonts import UnicodeCIDFont
pdfmetrics.registerFont(UnicodeCIDFont("STSong-Light"))

enc = pdfencrypt.StandardEncryption( 
    "", canPrint=1, canModify=0, canCopy=0, canAnnotate=0 
) 

self._Report = SimpleDocTemplate( 
    save_file, 
    topmargin=0.75*inch, bottommargin=0.75*inch, 
    rightmargin=0.70*inch, leftmargin=0.70*inch, 
    showBoundary=0, 
    author="xxx", 
    title="xxx", 
    subject=xxx", 
    encrypt=enc 
)
```

For non Asian languages the encryption works as expected. When we use Asian fonts with encryption the pdf cannot be read by adobe reader. For example with simplified Chinese we get a "Cannot find the font "STSong-Light" error from Adobe Reader.

Anyone have any ideas on what encryption is breaking to not make this work?

Comment: Not that a workaround is a solution, but does it work in other PDF viewers?  This might give some hint if it's something to do with the way Adobe Reader processes PDFs and give some idea of where to look for a solution?

Comment: I tired other pdf readers and they give the same error, "Cannot find STSong-Light".  These same viewers work fine as long as encryption is not enabled.  I diff'ed the same file with encryption enabled and disabled and they both have the exact same font definitions.  The only thing that differs is the streams are encrypted.  Somehow the encryption is breaking something internal in the pdf structure.

Comment: Hmm, then I think this might be a bug with ReportLab.  You might try reporting it on the ReportLab users mailing list.  http://two.pairlist.net/mailman/listinfo/reportlab-users

Comment: I did,  got no answer.  Might try again but reworded and with some new info.

Comment: Another idea, though it's not automated, is to add the encryption later using something like Acrobat.  Not open source or free or automated, but at least it would get the desired result (I hope).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. This might not solve your problem.
But, If I specify it into Japanese, 
you can solve it by installing `TTFont`(in this example it is IPA gothic),
and set the font.

So, by installing another languages fonts, you can solve the problem though 
this is not cool.

```
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter,A4
from reportlab.pdfbase import pdfmetrics
from reportlab.pdfbase.ttfonts import TTFont

fontname = 'IPA Gothic'
pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont(fontname,'{directory that you put the font}/ipag.ttf'))
p = canvas.Canvas(response,pagesize=A4)
p.setFont(fonatname,13)
p.drawString(100,100,u'日本語,中国語,韓国語')
p.showPage()
p.save()
```